# What does color column must be categorical, not numeric mean in R?

Tags: r

```
library(ggplot2)

library(GGally)

ggpairs(diab, aes(color=diabetes, alpha=0.75), lower=list(continuous="smooth"))+ theme_bw()+

labs(title="Correlation Plot of Variance(diabetes)")+

theme(plot.title=element_text(face='bold',color='black',hjust=0.5,size=12))



Error in ggally_statistic(data = data, mapping = mapping, na.rm = na.rm,  : 
  `mapping` color column must be categorical, not numeric
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to assign colors, you must give categories to `ggplot`. A numerical vector can have infinite values, so the function doesn't know how to assign colors to it, thus you need a `factor`. You can transform `diabetes` to a factor by doing:

```
diab$diabetes = as.factor(diab$diabetes)
```